# Необходимо с помощью чистого JS (без сторонних библиотек) получить данные с сервера

Tags: javascript

**Исходные данные:**
Возьмем любой сайт, в котором содержимое разбито по html страницам. Например: https://hd.21lordfilm-0.xyz/filmy1/, или любой другой сайт не на ReactJS с содержимым, разбитым по страницам.

**Задача:**
Без помощи сторонних библиотек на чистом JS нужно получить список элементов со всех страниц, как бы получается спарсить.
Как мне, находясь на 1 странице, получить элементы с любой другой ?

**Желательно:**
Данные получить в виде массива объектов.

**Что я пробовал:**
При помощи fetch я получил без проблем содержимое нужной мне страницы, но только в виде текста (строки), преобразовать в JSON мне не удалось, то есть метод JSON.parse() не помог.
Как я понял мне необходимо в любом случае работать с JSON, но какими методами пользоваться я не совсем понимаю. Фрагменты кода не прикладываю, так как в этом нет никакого смысла.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150556/discussion-on-question-by-------js--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.